# sum of column in XML publisher

Tags: xml, bi-publisher, oracle-bi, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I have a column I am getting in the RTF TEMPLATE that calculates the sum by using -`<?sum(current-group()/PAYMENT[../PAYMENT != ''])?>`

```
***Tax deduction*** 
Description                        current                                              YTD
Voluntary                 `<?sum(current-group()/PAYMENT[../PAYMENT != ''])?>`        `<?sum(current-group()/YEAR)?`>
Involuntary               <?PAYMENT?>                                                 `<?sum(current-group()/YEAR)?`>
Pre tax                   `<?sum(current-group()/PAYMENT[../PAYMENT != ''])?>`        `<?sum(current-group()/YEAR)?`>
```

I want to calculate the sum total of the `current` value and `YTD` column value. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried just adding them together? sum()+sum()?

Comment: Can you share the XML and Template? And also give an example of what you expect from the template?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column by name, (say CASH), you can calculate the sum of the column values simply by using < ? sum(CASH) ? >, without using repeating-group.